# Criptografia de URL em C# ASP.NET mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, criptografia

O método q estou usando para criptografar a URL está dando certo, mas as vezes ele faz a criptografia com uma / no meio isso faz com que ele não ache a rota desejada.

```
 public static string EncryptQueryString(string clearText)
        {
            byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return clearText;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar o `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` como tratamento aos caracteres especiais gerados pelo ofuscamento.

```
public static string EncryptQueryString(string clearText)
{
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clearText);
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo agora está aparecendo o seguinte erro: Um valor possivelmente perigoso Request.Path foi detectado no cliente (%).

Comment: Isso é outra coisa, de onde veio essa mensagem? Mostre um exemplo de uma url gerada

Comment: esse foi o URL que deu o erro: http://localhost:52257/Home/Index/7n0d%252bUcybPgim2Dk1OcXDA%253d%253d?nomeEmpresa=eZD5Pq9C6IXZ8FbOVOV90g%253d%253d

Comment: Não há nada de errado com a URL, a mensagem de erro deve ser do seu antivírus, firewall ou regras de proxy da sua empresa

Comment: Mas seu eu der o deploy o erro vai continuar pros usuários?

Comment: manda um print dessa tela de erro

Comment: Link pro print: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OBlKxBK4Xs5-WdcB6f7mj33mh7NaZj96

Comment: agora eu entendi, mas pq você quer encriptar um parametro da rota?

Comment: por exemplo, quando o cara acessar uma tela de alterar perfil por exemplo, no url fica o id do usuário, aí qualquer usuário logado pode simplesmente, digitar o id e ter acesso aos dados de outro usuário, eu pensei nessa maneira, teria outro jeito de barrar essa brecha na segurança?